# Can .htaccess redirect based on a PHP script result?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want all the incoming traffic to be tunneled through a PHP script, simply by uploading the script to the server and adding a few lines to my .htaccess. Is it - or something similar - possible?

E.g.:

1. I visit a page.
2. The PHP script gets the whole URL, and gives back the redirect target URL to the .htaccess.
3. The .htaccess redirects only if the URL has been modified by the PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

Something very similar can be done using Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) more traditional rules.  Or as you've noted in the conversation to @Zak's answer perhaps using an internal redirect.

Here is an example sequence:

1. User visits page (e.g. `http://myhost.com/my_area/my_file.jpg`)
2. `.htaccess` is configured to pass *all* requests for `/myarea` (or even `/`) to a php script.  (e.g. `handle-url.php`)  ([Example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214507/6287702))
3. The logic in `handle-url.php` can now do any of several things:

   1. Return an error
   2. Redirect the user to any url using the the `header("Location: URL)` method as mentioned by @Zak  (e.g. `http://myhost.com/file_area/my_file.jpg` )
   3. Directly read the file from disk and return the data to the user.  ([Example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user))

Take a look at the `mod_rewrite`'s advanced example page. Depending on what exactly you need to do there may be other options.

For example, [On-the-fly Content-Regeneration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/advanced.html#on-the-fly-content) may be helpful.  As may `FallbackResource`.

Comment: I need a solution in which Apache makes the last redirect, not PHP. I have tons of existing RewriteRules, that I don't want to implement in PHP. (And the new logic that I want to add is too complex for Apache, so in this case I need PHP.)

Comment: hmm. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1390754/6287702  It's possible such a virtual redirect (i.e. lacking a ptoto+host) can trigger a subrequest through mod_rewite.  Can't test this at the moment.  Worst case senario, you could just proxy out the back of your php script and pass through the reply.  But that's getting ugly.

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` is fired BEFORE the `PHP` script.  Look at `.htaccess` as an extension of you web server (Apache) settings.  You will not be able to "send" something to `.htaccess` as it's a configuration file for a server, not an engine itself.  Conversly you can use `PHP`'s native `header redirect`

**PHP**

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: Maybe I could make Apache do a subrequest, so that at first it makes an internal redirect to the script, and then makes an external redirect - if needed - based on the script's return value, that could be stored in a server- or environment variable. Is it impossible?

Comment: RewriteMap - which I don't know too much about - seems to be promising as well. Except the fact that it can't be used in .htaccess context.

Comment: This one is interesting as well, I'll read more about it: _%{LA-F:variable} can be used to perform an internal (filename-based) sub-request, to determine the final value of variable. Most of the time, this is the same as LA-U above._ (Source: [httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond))